# Native -> JS communication in WKWebView IFrames

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, uikit, wkwebview

In WKWebView we can call ObjectiveC/Swift code using webkit message handlers `webkit.messageHandlers.<handler>.pushMessage(message).`

And this works for IFrames too.

Is there a way to respond to this by calling into the IFrame?

Currently the `evaluateJavaScript:` API supports communication only to the main frame.

Comment: if evaluateJavaScript contains only JS function's name and arguments, then  the simple idea is to use some JS code in the main frame for proxying into IFrame(s).

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a JavaScript bridge to IOS
take a looik at : http://www.priyaontech.com/2014/12/native-%E2%80%93-js-bridging-on-ios8-using-wkwebview/
and
http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html

Hope this helps

Comment: This example doesn't really cover frames. While it would allow a frame to communicate with native code, it doesn't address communicating with an iframe from native code.

Comment: Any luck @robotspacer?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a real good library for a Javascript bridge (it supports `UIWebview` and `WKWebview`) : https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge

The bridge can be used for **native to JS** or **JS to native** communication. They've made quite a good job you should have a look on it.

On web side you have to add some JavaScript code, so that the bridge is present on HTML side, their doc shows a `setupWebViewJavascriptBridge` method to add (Read [Usage](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge#usage) part of their readme). 
In the end it up to you wether you add this code directly in the page, or through iOS using `evaluateJavaScript`

Comment: This is a complex example that seems to open a URL in a hidden iframe, which the native code can intercept and then pull data out of the URL? This isn't the best option we have these days, and I'm not seeing any evidence that it addresses the question of communicating with an iframe from native code.

Answer (score -2):

synchronous communication between two different processes is [not possible](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/206xxdiurnffagr/206/206_introducing_the_modern_webkit_api.pdf?dl=1)